# How to Route the Request from one Path to Different Urls Based on Condition with Zuul?

Tags: java, spring-boot, url-routing, netflix-zuul

I have spring-boot zuul routing web app. What I'm trying to achieve is to route the request from the specified path to different urls based on some condition. So, I'm looking for something like this:

`application.properties` zuul routing props:

```
zuul.routes.mypath.path=/mypath/** #lets say zuul web app hosted on localhost:7777
zuul.routes.mypath.url1=http://localhost:8888/path
zuul.routes.mypath.url2=http://localhost:9999/anotherpath
```

And, then, probably using Zuul Route Filter or smth else I want to access this `url1` and `url2` and do the routing based on my condition.

P.S. I have working solution so far using Zuul Route Filter, and `application.properties` like below. I just grab `my.custom.url.prop` in the Filter and route the request there if I met my condition. But, I'm looking for the right way, "Zuul" way of doing it.

```
zuul.routes.mypath.path=/mypath/** #lets say zuul web app hosted on localhost:7777
zuul.routes.mypath.url=http://localhost:8888/path
my.custom.url.prop=http://localhost:9999/anotherPath
```

Some code from the Filter to make the question clearer:

```
public Object run() {
    ....

    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    try {

        if (isRoutingCondition(ctx.getRequest())) {
            ctx.setRouteHost(urlFromMyCustomProp);
        } else { 
            ctx.setRouteHost(RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRouteHost());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question. Zuul already routes  URLs based on URL pattern. Are you looking for something other than URL pattern?

Comment: I want to find the way to route the request for the same "URL pattern" to different routes(2 or more different urls) based on some conditions

Comment: Your issue seems to very similar to the Dynamic Routing issue discussed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2227).

Comment: @IndraBasak Thanks, took a look at this. Seems like I already have similar solution as suggested in this post, but I'm trying to find standard/right Zuul way of doing it. Though, probably it is the only way it can be done with Zuul.